# Iterate in array extract and add to new list if object value is true in javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have an array like below and I want to extract objects and sub-array and create a new array if the selected object value is true

```
menu: [
  {
    category_name: "snacks",
    selected: true
    items: [
      {
        item_name: "burger",
        price: 00,
        bestseller: false
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    category_name: "tiffins",
    selected: false
    items: [
      {
        item_name: "idly",
        price: 00,
        bestseller: false
      }
    ]
  },
]
```

i want new array would be like this

```
new_menu: [
  {
    category_name: "snacks",
    items: [
      {
        item_name: "burger",
        price: 00,
        bestseller: false
      }
    ]
  },
]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try this:

```js
const new_menu = menu
  // Get the selected items
 .filter(m => m.sellected)
  // Get rid of the `sellected` property
 .map(({ sellected, ...m }) => m)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var new_menu = menu.filter(function (el) {
  return el.sellected;
});
```

If you want to exclude `sellected` key then:

```
var new_menu = menu.filter(function (el) {
  return el.sellected;
}).map(function(elem) {
     return {'category_name': elem.category_name, 'items': elem.items}
});
```